# S Note 4 - How Many Books

Tags: google, google-play-books

How can I tell my number of uploads in Google Play Books?
I have a bunch of books in my Google books.  It seems like I cannot add any more unless I delete some.  I found out that the limit is 1000 but I cannot figure out how to find how many I have already uploaded on to Google Books.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the [Google Dashboard](https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard?pli=1), which details ALL data usage of your account. It includes a rundown about your Gmail converations, your synched Contacts, your connected Android Devices, usage and storage of Google Drive, Calendar, Photos, etc., in addition to the target of your question, how many books are in your Google Books.